# Custom Object is not visible in report making option

Tags: reporting

I have a custom object "BD lead" . When I try to make a report for this object, I am not able to find this object in report builder.

Comment: Try looking in the Category (section on the left of the Create Report window) if it's marked with All when you try searching your Report Type.

Answer (score 11):

When you create a custom object in salesforce.
You have check for a check box in  **Optional Features** -->Allow Reports.
So please try doing that.

Comment: My flag is showing checked but my object is still not showing..Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

- Go Back to your object **Setup > Create > Your_Object**
- Click on **Edit**
- At the bottom under **Optional Features**, check **Allow Reports**
  and Save it

Also a kind of possible problem is after creating the report type, some fields are missing in the report builder. This is because of custom fields have not been added to the report type.
To resolve this,

- Go to **Setup > Create > Report Types**.
- Click on your Custom Report Type.
- At the bottom under **Fields Available for Reports** click **Edit
  Layout**.
- Then drag and drop the fields you want to display on report from right hand side panel and save it.

Answer (score 3):

Good amount of details, power of community!!! great to see, still just thought of adding this picture !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got into the same situation & found that if you expand other reports folder
(Last folder ), you'll be able to find your custom object.

Hope this may help!

Thanks,
Dhrumil

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even though I clicked the "Allow Reports" button, I also needed to create a Custom Report Type in order to be able to create a report.

**Setup > (search for) Report Types > New Custom Report Type**